# Yii2 creating global dynamic values for all application's actions

Tags: php, oop, yii2

I want to pass current path info, i.e controller/action/params, to a widget that uses another model to generate some static HTML contents in the views of the application, including the layout too.

In-order to achieve that goal, I have defined the following controller `AppController` and I make all of my app controllers extends it instead of `yii\web\Controller;`

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;
use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;

class AppController extends Controller
{
  public function __construct($id, $module, $config = array()) {
    parent::__construct($id, $module, $config);
    $this->view->params['path2'] = Yii::$app->controller->id;
  }  
  /*
  public function beforeAction($action) {
    parent::beforeAction($action);
    $this->view->params['path2'] = Yii::$app->controller->id;
  }  */

}
```

And, for example, in SiteController:

```
class SiteController extends AppController
{...
```

**The problem** is in any view of any `SiteController` action, for eaxmple `about` `echo $this->params['path2']` returns blank while I expect it to echo `site`. In addition, uncommenting `beforeAction` makes all SiteController actions produces blank pages.

I need any way to allow, globally, set `$this->params['path2']` value to be the current `controller/action/params` regardless what routs rewrites is.

Comment: why not just use Yii::$app->controller->id from any place? it should work just fine without adding it as a parameter to the view.

Comment: Imagine?! and the widget itself can access them, `Yii::$app->controller->actionParams` and `Yii::$app->controller->getRoute()`. And It should be more simple solution rather than creating new parent controller. @MihaiP. Thank you very much for the idea.

Comment: yep, you should be able to access everything from Yii:$app anywhere. Just take from there what you need.